# Поиск элемента в АВЛ-дереве

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево

Есть АВЛ-дерево, нужно проверить, есть ли в нем заданный ключ. Если есть, то вернуть указатель на данный узел, если нет, то вывести, что данного ключа в дереве нет. Проблема в том, что при вводе ключа, который в есть в дереве функция работает правильно, а при вводе несуществующего ключа меняет 1 элемент дерева. В чем проблема?
struct Node

```
{
    int key;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    int height;
};

struct Node* FindKey(struct Node* node,int k){
    if(node != NULL)
    {
        if(node->key=k) return node;
        if(node->key>k) return FindKey(node->left,k);
        else return FindKey(node->right, k);
    }
    printf("There is no key");
}
```

Comment: Вы  опечатались  if(node->key=k) return node; А нужно ==

Comment: Спасибо большое